# Android application backend storage

Tags: android, database

I am learning how to develop android apps and I have read the basic tutorials. I do not have an extensive knowledge on app development.

I am trying to develop an app to save user information and retrieve them, using their login from any where. While googling I find that sqlite will be good for saving the data. But I can also understand that Sqlite will be in the android device itself.(Please correct me if i am wrong) But, I want the user to be able to download the app and login from anywhere and view their data.

How can i do it. What is the best database option? Is storing in cloud a good option? I have read that Parse Core and AWS Lamba provide cloud storage or how else can it be done. I am developing my app using JAVA through android studio. Please help me on this.

Comment: In your case have to store user info on server.

Comment: I was using parse and quickblox with android apps but I prefere quickblox.

Comment: thank you,will read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your requirement, you have to use a centralized database. since Sqlite database is internal to android you can't make use of it, in this case. since you are a beginner in android you can start reading about accessing central database from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). and basically cloud server is used for scalable applications. if you think you're application is scalable, you can use cloud servers.

Comment: Yes my application would be scalable. Thank you, will got through the link

Comment: accept answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes you understand it right, when referring to sqlite it's for local DB.
I would recommend you to go with [Parse](http://parse.com/) cause it really simple and easy, or go with [AppEnging](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/) for the great integration with AndroidStudio and Android.